# I want to add dynamic input box on button click and then save the value into database (postgresql)

Tags: python, html, django

This is my button

```
<input type="button" value="add-entry" id="add">
```

This is the ajax call made on clicking the button

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").click(function(e){
        event.preventDefault()
        var htmlAppend='<div><table><tr><td><input type="text" name="user-name"></td></tr>'+
        //  '<tr><td><input type="text" name="e-mail"></td></tr>'+
        '<input type="button" value="delete" id="delete" /></table></div>'
     $('#items').append(htmlAppend);
     localStorage.setItem("htmlAppend", htmlAppend);
    });

     var htmlAppend = localStorage.getItem("htmlAppend");
     if (htmlAppend) {
        $("#items").append(htmlAppend);
     }


    $('body').on('click','#delete',function(e){
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
    });

});
</script>
```

The problem is if I click on button 2 times then the name of the input field will be same then how can I fetch the value of two different text boxes with the same name.
Please suggest any other way if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello @Rimjhim Gupta as from what I understood you are trying to add elements dynamically on the page and then retrieve their values. I see two possible variants to solve this problem: 1) add a counter variable which value will increase every time you click on `#add`button and add it's value to the new elements name. In this case Names of newely created elements would always be different and you will be able to manipulate them as needed. for example:

```
let counter = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").click(function(e){
        event.preventDefault()
        var htmlAppend=`<div><table><tr><td><input type="text" name="user-name"${counter}></td></tr>`+
        `<tr><td><input type="text" name="e-mail"${counter}></td></tr>`+
        `<input type="button" value="delete" id="delete" /></table></div>`
     $('#items').append(htmlAppend);
     localStorage.setItem("htmlAppend", htmlAppend);
     counter++;
    });

     var htmlAppend = localStorage.getItem("htmlAppend");
     if (htmlAppend) {
        $("#items").append(htmlAppend);
     }


    $('body').on('click','#delete',function(e){
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
    });

});
```

Here I've used string interpolation (check it in the internet, it is something I use all the time).

2) Second possible variant is to go through the parent DIV using loop (I prefer for loop for that) and retrieve data from each div separately. But I personally prefer 1st variant. If you need any additional hints/tips let me know.